# How can I determine what license a video is under on youtube?

Tags: licensing

This [video_1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t36jZG07MYc&list=PLUl4u3cNGP63oMNUHXqIUcrkS2PivhN3k&index=2) claims it is under "Creative Commons BY-NC-SA", while this [video_2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4qfdCwys2ew) does not.

How can I determine what license a video (such as video_2) is under on youtube.

Comment: If there is no license specified, the default license is "all rights reserved" (i.e. all the normal protections of copyright law apply). See also [Does Sourceforge have a default licence?](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/2940/does-sourceforge-have-a-default-licence) - The situation there is about code and sourceforge, but the principle would be the same for videos and YouTube.

Comment: If you follow that page back to the original publisher's page (Khan Academy) it says at the bottom of the page (which includes the video embedded in it, as well) that it is Creative Commons (Non Commercial). Whether this license applies to the video recording as well might be a matter of interpretation of the notice on that page.

Comment: @Brandin Is [this](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/differential-equations/laplace-transform/properties-of-laplace-transform/v/dirac-delta-function) the page you mentioned? I didn't find anything involves license except for "Khan Academy is a 501(c)(3) nonprofit organization", are you talking about "501(c)(3)"?

Comment: Yes it is that page. You have to scroll to the bottom and wait for the rest of the page to load, and then look below the video transcript. But it's a bit unclear to me whether they mean the transcript is supposed to be CC, or the video, or both.

Comment: @Brandin  Thanks a lot! Please move your comments to answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: I could swear that Youtube used to have "Standard Youtube license" under normal videos, but now apparently they don't show it anymore.

Answer (score 1):

### You find the copyright owner and ask them

Unfortunately, only the copyright owner can grant licences and the onus is on you to demonstrate that you have a valid chain of licences back to them.

Comment: Are you referring to video_1 or video_2?

Comment: @whnlp both of them

Answer (score 0):

[Youtube terms of service](https://www.youtube.com/static?template=terms) define the minimum rights that a video's uploader grants to a youtube user:

> License to Other Users
>
> You also grant each other user of the Service a worldwide, non-exclusive, royalty-free license to access your Content through the Service, and to use that Content, including to reproduce, distribute, prepare derivative works, display, and perform it, only as enabled by a feature of the Service (such as video playback or embeds). For clarity, this license does not grant any rights or permissions for a user to make use of your Content independent of the Service.

This grant allows anyone to view uploaded videos on youtube, and does not provide any permissions for using them in any capacity outside of youtube.

Unless a particular video is marked as being released under another (additional) license, these terms would apply.